# Add a docstring to an entire Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, docstring

In my office, we frequently create Jupyter notebooks with helper functions for a project, then use %run magic to import those functions into other working notebooks as we need them. We always add a docstring to each function so new users don't need to go open the source notebook in order to use them, but I would also like to add a note-book level docstring to tell the user what functions are even available in the first place.

For example, I have a notebook titled user_tools.ipynb with functions foo() and bar(). When someone runs %run 'user_tools.ipynb', they can type help(foo) for documentation about the foo function. I would like the ability for the user to also type help(user_tools) to produce a list of available functions in that notebook, such as :

```
Functions
---------
   foo() : 
      foo description
   bar() : 
      bar description
```

But so far variations of help(user_tools.ipynb), help("user_tools.ipynb") etc. haven't worked.

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Why using notebooks to create modules and not just create "normal", (real) python modules instead ?

Comment: It was an accessibility decision. Many members of the team are new or novice Python users who are most comfortable with Jupyter notebooks.